# NSFetchedResultsController on secondary UITableView - how to query data?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I am creating a core-data based Navigation iPhone app with multiple screens. Let's say it is a flash-card application. The data model is very simple, with only two entities: Language, and CardSet. There is a one-to-many relationship between the Language entity and the CardSet entities, so each Language may contain multiple CardSets. In other words, Language has a one-to-many relationship Language.cardSets which points to the list of CardSets, and CardSet has a relationship CardSet.language which points to the Language.

There are two screens: (1) An initial TableView screen, which displays the list of languages; and (2) a secondary TableView screen, which displays the list of CardSets in the Language.

In the initial screen, which lists the languages, I am using NSFetchedResultsController to keep the list of languages up-to-date. The screen passes the Language selected to the secondary screen.

On the secondary screen, I am trying to figure out whether I should again use an NSFetchedResultsController to maintain the list of CardSets, or if I should work through Language.cardSets to simply pull the list out of the object model. The latter makes the most sense programatically because I already have the Language - but then it would not automatically be updated on changes.

I have looked at the NSFetchedResultsController documentation, and it seems like I can easily create predicates based on attributes - but not relationships. I.e., I can create the following NSFetchedResultsController:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name LIKE[c] 'Chuck Norris'"];
```

How can I access my data through the direct relationship - Language.cardSets - and also have the table auto-update using NSFetchedResultsController? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a `NSFetchedResultsController` in the detail you get automatic notification of any changes to the set which is a net win.  Personally I would use a second `NSFetchedResultsController` just for its convenience.

Comment: In the end, I just used an `NSFetchedResultsController` and made it an assumption that my entities had unique names.

Comment: You can tell the underling NSFetchRequest to only return uniques.  Not sure if you are aware of that flag.